# Spring boot resttemplate get request found 401 unauthorized exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

Following code snippet receives **401 unauthorized** exception :

```
String uri = "https://api/example.json?status=all";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
ResponseEntity <String> results = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class;
```

Comment: does api has any authentication? like oauth?

Comment: on postman , i didnt set any authentication but its working fine there

Comment: can you add an example that you are trying in postman

Comment: @Deadpool  how could i understand it contans oauth? i just send simple https request on postman; just seen there is param only

Comment: what headers are you passing in postman?

Comment: content-type application/json

Comment: This information is not helpful to me, please add complete example

Comment: as i said , i just sent `https://api/example.json?status=all` with param `status=all` and header is `application/json``

Comment: Hello @atiqkhaled How you have implemented authentication and authorization? Share more with details and code

Comment: can you post the server code please?

Comment: @atiqkhaled Can you please provide CURL request from postman?

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati its working when using apache `httpclient` . I don`t know why not happening for resttemplate.